# Pages do not load completely before being displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm using Safari and I have never seen this problem in an other website, when i want to go from page to page in my website, sometimes the pages ( never the same ) do not load completely before being displayed. All my pages have a unique page and link, so normally when we click on a link, the page is refreshed before being showed.

I find myself with a half page loaded instead of all my gallery, and always need to refresh to have the real page.

Why I am faced with this problem and how can I solve it ?
Is there a way to automatically refresh if my page isn't loaded or isn't this the best solution?

Comment: sometimes i have this line in my page and need to refresh to have a clean page -> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
(anonyme function ) — my page.html:38  -  An error occurred while attempting to load the resource

Comment: I had faced similar issues, but in my case it was my hosting company which was at fault. It always failed requests for some resources. I could easily see it in browser console though and it was not browser dependent.

Comment: So firstly fix this error

Comment: My suggestion is that if you have any tool in safari to inspect page for console or request send from page, something like firebug addon in firefox browser. That help you to track any failure in request sending and receiving or any scripting related error generate in that page. That  may cause a issue.

Comment: Totally agree @MohitBhardwaj i suspect them too but not sure, i'm with bluehost !!

Comment: can I add something who will help me in Safari @Krishna_K_Systematix

Comment: how can I fix this sort of error @A.Wolff

Comment: That's a synthax error. You need to post relevant code in question itself with enough context so we can check what error do you have.

Comment: Yes, you can enable Web Development Tools in safari and use it to track error.

Comment: Ok @A.Wolff in my page i can have some links to images not uploaded yet, and sometimes i have a half page with errors like -> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (2-14.jpg, line 0), [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (2-6.jpg, line 0), ...

Comment: I already use it @Krishna_K_Systematix but sometimes i only have a part of [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (2-14.jpg, line 0), instead of all my list of images ?